# I updated my BIOS a while back and I've been having this same issue even when I roll back

Tags: windows-10, bios, troubleshooting

I've been having this weird issue where the Windows lock-screen/sign-in screen will stick to my desktop background unless I either refresh it or select it all with my mouse.

I reinstalled Windows as well and it went a way for a while but suddenly came back. I tried almost everything so I have no idea what to do now.

The first image is it stuck to my background and the second image is it refreshed thus being gone until I restart my PC again and it shows up again.

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: @harrymc I tried that and it shows no errors. Any other ideas?

Comment: You can try updating all your drivers.  Once that is done and if you sill have the issue, then update BIOS, back up and install Windows fresh.

Comment: Your screenshot does not make it clear what problem you are currently facing. If you didn't choose to "keep nothing," then the problem is likely with just the profile.

Comment: @Ramhound That seems like it did the job! I wonder how that happened or kept happening. Thanks so much! its been bugging me for a month. I wonder if this was some placebo or something because this never happened until I tried to update my bios.

Comment: @CaptainFuso - The two events are unlikely to be connected.

Comment: @John The issue came back and I've tried this and the issue still persists. I have a video of it if that would help at all. Sorry about making it a 2nd post I'm still new to this site.

Comment: As I suggested, you should update all drivers and then back up and reinstall Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Since everything you tried (including a Repair that kept the User Profile) did not work, you should back everything up, update all of drivers and then reinstall Windows.

You can do this 2 ways:

(1) Download the Windows ISO, start it, delete partitions and install Windows fresh. This is the best way here.

(2) You can run a Repair Install and choose the option to Keep Nothing. This is very close to (1) and is easier overall.

Keeping Data keeps the User Profile and if the profile has an issue, Repair Keep Data will not fix the issue.